# Saddle bag for iPad? (10.5)

Tags: saddle, bags

I’m looking for a way to carry an iPad on a 80km commute.

I don’t like backpack, as it’s heavy on shoulders and rack for just an iPad  feels overkill.

So looking for saddlebag big enough for an iPad. Any suggestions / ideas?

(Carbon Fiber CX bike).

Open to suggestions.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service/learning material recommendations or item valuations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead describe the situation or specific problem you are trying to solve, or try chatting about it in The Velodrome.

Comment: But note that an iPad is not incredibly large.  Any number of panniers should be able to accept one, along with a bit of padding.  (Note that you will need a rack in any event.)

Comment: There are large, flat saddlebags that could carry an iPad or even a laptop. And there are handlebar bags that could carry an iPad. One of these is probably your simplest option. Check out [Rivendell](https://www.rivbike.com/collections/bags) or [Ortlieb](https://www.ortlieb.com/us/products/bike-bags/handlebar-bags)

Comment: Try a frame bag. That goes inside the triangle. You don’t want an iPad hanging out in a seat bag.

Comment: Not sure how large an iPad is, maybe it even fits in the jersey pockets? Otherwise I just want to point out that many handlebar bags (+mount) are quite heavy. In comparison, rear racks start at around 300g + light panniers at around 700g.

Comment: Consider making your own framebag for a bespoke fit.  They're surprisingly easy to make, needing some waterproof material, internal padding for lining, some velcro zipties to go around the frame and perhaps a zip.

Comment: @Michael iPads are about 240mmx180mm, so not going to fit in a pocket.

Comment: @Criggie I thought about framebags, but then I have no water :-/.

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev sounds like a good new question "how to design a custom framebag for an ipad"   Depending on your frame design, you might choose to position the tablet to the left of the frame leaving acces on the right side to the bottle cages.

Comment: An ipad mini should fit in a jersey pocket, but sweat could be an issue.   If its full-sized, consider modding your jersey to have one large center pocket and two smaller ones at the sides,